# Set Custom Position of Datables Length Menu

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-4, material-design, datatables-1.10

I am using datatables for my project.

I want to set custom position for my filters, pagination and search option.
I am using [Material MDB Pro](https://mdbootstrap.com) for my CSS.

Now I want to position my length menu below the table as shown in this picture.

[image: I want it like this]

So I tried using this code:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
    } );
```

But this brings everything down. Even the search! I want to keep Search and Export buttons on the top and only pagination and length menu to be down.

My Code is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $('#dtMaterialDesignExample').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [[5,10, 25, 50, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, "All"]],
      dom: 'Blfrtip',
      fixedHeader: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                title: 'bizRTC CDR <?php date('d-m-Y'); ?>',
                 customize: function (csv) {
                     return "Enjoy the file"+csv;
                  },
                   className: 'btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect space',
            },
            {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            title: 'CDR <?php echo date('d-m-Y'); ?>',
            customize: function ( doc ) {
                            doc.content.splice( 0, 0, {
                                text: "bizRTC CDR"
                            } );
            },
            className: 'btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect space',
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',

                title: 'bizRTC CDR <?php date('d-m-Y'); ?>',
                message: "Call Records",
                className: 'btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect space',


            },
        ],

      responsive: {
            details: {
                display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal( {
                    header: function ( row ) {
                        var data = row.data();
                        return 'Details for '+data[0]+' '+data[1];
                    }
                } ),
                renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll( {
                    tableClass: 'table'
                } )
            }
        },
        "drawCallback": function () {
            $('.dataTables_paginate > .pagination').addClass('pagination pagination-circle pg-blue mb-0');
        }
});
```

**Edit 1:**

After adding the following in my code  :

```
dom: '<"row"<"float-left"B><"float-right"f>><"row"<"float-left"i><"float-right"p>>rtlp',
```

[image: Edited Code]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this one:

It shows buttons on the top left side, search on the top right side, per page on the bottom left side, table info on the bottom middle side and pagination on the bottom right side.

[image]

For Bootstrap v3:

```
dom: '<"pull-left"B><"pull-right"f>rt<"row"<"col-sm-4"l><"col-sm-4"i><"col-sm-4"p>>'
```

For bootstrap v4:

```
dom: '<"float-left"B><"float-right"f>rt<"row"<"col-sm-4"l><"col-sm-4"i><"col-sm-4"p>>'
```

[Demo](http://live.datatables.net/hidihafe/2)

Comment: Hi I tried this and it now shows me two pagintion buttons i am adding the result in my question

Comment: I added this to my code  `dom: 'Blfrtip',
      dom: '<"row"<"float-left"B><"float-right"f>><"row"<"float-left"i><"float-right"p>>rtlp',`

Comment: Yeah this works except this :  `Showing 1 to 5 of 25 entries` is still show above the table

Comment: How do i bring the text below ? underneath the select option

Comment: @Rajan, may I know where is `select` option? Anyways I've updated my solution to show info in the middle downside.

Comment: by select i meant the page length. Just another question if you can answer in one line:  Is it possible to show Export Buttons as HTML Select / Dropdown button or any other element

Comment: @Rajan, check [DataTable collections](https://datatables.net/reference/button/collection). Hope it'll help you out.